# How to know service/topic detail information from remote

Tags: rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm ysuga. Japanese Robotics Engineer.

I'm currently developing a Java library and tools for connecting ROS topic/service with other robotics suites.

I want to know the way how to investigate the topic/service detail information that can be acquired by "rosmsg show ..." or "rossrv show...".
I guess these command-line tools get the information by using the host pc's file system. However, I want to develop the Java library that can be universally used even if the remote PC does not have ROS library and file system.

Is it possible to acquire the information from the remote pc w/o ROS filesystem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11122/how-to-know-service/topic-detail-information-from-remote/) by [ysuga](https://answers.ros.org/users/1044/ysuga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ysuga](https://answers.ros.org/users/1044/ysuga/) on 2011-09-06**:\

> > Lorenz Yes, I know the rosjava. But it looks strongly coupled with the ROS filesystem, so it may not be installed to the windows and other non-supported machines. I want to make more dynamic and universal tool for any ROS users including beginners:-)

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-09-06**:
For using the messages in Java, have a look at the new rosjava implementation (http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ysuga,

I guess there is no simple way to do that.
The two solutions I would advice are:

1. Make function which calls "rosmsg show"/"rossrv show" on the remote host (the one with ROS installed) and forward the results to your computer (the one without ROS).
2. Modify rosmsg and rossrv scripts so they search on a remote host.

Hope this will help you,

Guido

---

Originally posted by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) with karma: 514 on 2011-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-09-06**:
If 1) is OK, a simple ssh user@host "rosmsg show..." might do the trick.